# Calculate slope, length and angle of a specific part / side / line on a contour?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, angle

[image: Original Picture which is loaded]

I got two detected contours in an image and need the diameter between the two vertical-edges of the top contour and the diameter between the vertical-edges of the lower contour. I achieved this with this code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math, os
import imutils

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 200, 100)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None, iterations=1)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, None, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# sorting the contours to find the largest and smallest one
c1 = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
c2 = min(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# determine the most extreme points along the contours
extLeft1 = tuple(c1[c1[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight1 = tuple(c1[c1[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extLeft2 = tuple(c2[c2[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight2 = tuple(c2[c2[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])

# show contour
cimg = cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (0,200,0), 2)

# set y of left point to y of right point
lst1 = list(extLeft1)
lst1[1] = extRight1[1]
extLeft1 = tuple(lst1)

lst2 = list(extLeft2)
lst2[1] = extRight2[1]
extLeft2= tuple(lst2)

# compute the distance between the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
dist1 = math.sqrt( ((extLeft1[0]-extRight1[0])**2)+((extLeft1[1]-extRight1[1])**2) )
dist2 = math.sqrt( ((extLeft2[0]-extRight2[0])**2)+((extLeft2[1]-extRight2[1])**2) )

# draw lines
cv2.line(cimg, extLeft1, extRight1, (255,0,0), 1)
cv2.line(cimg, extLeft2, extRight2, (255,0,0), 1)

# draw the distance text
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 0.5
fontColor = (255,0,0)
lineType = 1
cv2.putText(cimg,str(dist1),(155,100),font, fontScale, fontColor, lineType)
cv2.putText(cimg,str(dist2),(155,280),font, fontScale, fontColor, lineType)

# show image
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Result Image]

Now I would also need the angle of the slope lines on the bottom side of the upper contour.

[image: Target Image Demo 1]

Any ideas how I can get this? Is it possible using contours?

Or is it necessary to use HoughLinesP and sort the regarding lines somehow?

And continued question: Maybe its also possible to get function which describes parabola slope of that sides ?

[image: Target Image Demo 2]

Thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to obtain just the slopes. In order to know the slope, we can can use `cv2.HoughLines` to detect the bottom horizontal line, detect to end points of that line and from those, obtain the slopes. As an illustration,

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=int(dist2*0.66) )
```

on `edges` in your code gives 4 lines, and if we force the angle to be horizontal

```
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]

    # here we filter out non-horizontal lines
    if abs(theta - np.pi/2) > np.pi/180:
        continue

    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img_lines,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
```

we get:

[image]

For the extended question concerns with the parabolas, we first compose a function that returns the left and right points:

```
def horizontal_scan(gray_img, thresh=50, start=50):
    '''
    scan horizontally for left and right points until we met an all-background line
    @param thresh: threshold for background pixel
    @param start: y coordinate to start scanning
    '''

    ret = []
    thickness = 0
    for i in range(start,len(gray_img)):
        row = gray_img[i]

        # scan for left:
        left = 0
        while left < len(row) and row[left]<thresh:
            left += 1

        if left==len(row):
            break;
        # scan for right:
        right = left
        while right < len(row) and row[right] >= thresh:
            right+=1

        if thickness == 0:
            thickness = right - left

        # prevent sudden drop, error/noise
        if (right-left) < thickness//5:
            continue
        else:
            thickness = right - left

        ret.append((i,left,right))
    return ret

# we start scanning from extLeft1 down until we see a blank line
# with some tweaks, we can make horizontal_scan run on edges, 
# which would be simpler and faster
horizontal_lines = horizontal_scan(gray, start = extLeft1[1])

# check if horizontal_line[0] are closed to extLeft1 and extRight1
print(horizontal_lines[0], extLeft1, extRight1[0])
```

Note that we can use this function to find the end points of the horizontal line returned by HoughLines.

```
# last line of horizontal_lines would be the points we need:
upper_lowest_y, upper_lowest_left, upper_lowest_right = horizontal_lines[-1]

img_lines = img.copy()
cv2.line(img_lines, (upper_lowest_left, upper_lowest_y), extLeft1, (0,0,255), 1)
cv2.line(img_lines, (upper_lowest_right, upper_lowest_y), extRight1, (0,0,255),1)
```

and that gives:

[image]

Let's return to the extended question, where we have those left and right points:

```
left_points = [(x,y) for y,x,_ in horizontal_lines]
right_points = [(x,y) for y,_,x in horizontal_lines]
```

Obviously, they would not fit perfectly in a parabola, so we need some sort of approximation/fitting here. For that, we can build a LinearRegression model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
class BestParabola:
    def __init__(self, points):
        x_x2 = np.array([(x**2,x) for x,_ in points])
        ys = np.array([y for _,y in points])

        self.lr = LinearRegression()
        self.lr.fit(x_x2,ys)
        self.a, self.b = self.lr.coef_
        self.c = self.lr.intercept_
        self.coef_ = (self.c,self.b,self.a)

    def transform(self,points):
        x_x2 = np.array([(x**2,x) for x,_ in points])
        ys = self.lr.predict(x_x2)

        return np.array([(x,y) for (_,x),y in zip(x_x2,ys)])
```

And then, we can fit the given `left_points, right_points` to get the desired parabolas:

```
# construct the approximate parabola
# the parabollas' coefficients are accessible by BestParabola.coef_
left_parabola = BestParabola(left_points)
right_parabola = BestParabola(right_points)


# get points for rendering
left_parabola_points = left_parabola.transform(left_points)
right_parabola_points = right_parabola.transform(right_points)

# render with matplotlib, cv2.drawContours would work
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.plot(left_parabola_points[:,0], left_parabola_points[:,1], linewidth=3)
plt.plot(right_parabola_points[:,0], right_parabola_points[:,1], linewidth=3, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

The left parabola is not perfect, but you should work out that if need be :-)

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang for your perfect answer! Answered all my questions.<(^^)>

Comment: @Quang Hoang can i get the length of parabola selected for that side . If i modify my question ..then how to obtain length of each side of an image if it's side is arc shaped or curved